# syntax error near unexpected token `(' when running program in cygwin

Tags: c

having an issue while running my code on cygwin only getting one error which is at line 11. please spare me as i am a beginner. Trying to solve it from 8 hours straight but no luck
edited the error to match the source code
tried add an int between typedef int (*fun_ptr)... still same erroe

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define RED "\033[0;31m"
#define GREEN "\033[0;32m"
#define BLUE "\033[1;34m"
#define RESET "\033[0m"

typedef (*fun_ptr)(int**, int, int, char**, int, int);

void printBoard(int **board, int b_height, int b_width)
{
    int i, j;
    char ch;
    printf(":) ||");
    for (j = 0; j < b_width; j++)
    {
        printf(" %c |", 'A' + j);
    }
    printf("\n---++");
    for (j = 0; j < b_width; j++)
    {
        printf("===+");
    }
    for (i = 0; i < b_height; i++)
    {
        printf("\n %d ||", i + 1);
        for (j = 0; j < b_width; j++)
        {
            if (board[i][j] == -1)
            {
                ch = 'X';
                printf(" %s%c%s |", RED, ch, RESET);
                //printf(" X |");
            }
            else if (board[i][j] == -2) {
                ch = '0';
                printf(" %s%c%s |", GREEN, ch, RESET);
                //printf(" 0 |");
            }
            else {
                ch = '#';
                printf(" %s%c%s |", BLUE, ch, RESET);
                //printf(" # |");
            }
        }
        printf("\n---++");
        for (j = 0; j < b_width; j++)
        {
            printf("---+");
        }
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

error that i am getting

```
./source.c: line 11: syntax error near unexpected token `('
./source.c: line 11: `typedef (*fun_ptr) (int**, int, int, char**, int, int);'
```

Comment: are you using gcc - how are you compiling it?

Comment: The line in the code doesn't look like the line in the error message.

Comment: yes, gcc source.c -o source

Comment: So I don't think you posted the same source file that got the error.

Comment: @Barmar Since `*fun_ptr` is two tokens, not one, gcc would not have produced the message in the title. The message in the body of the question looks legit, but would not have been produced by that source file.

Comment: Please edit the question, make the title, code, and error message match.

Comment: What happens if you comment out line 11?

Comment: I would also recommend adding the gcc flag -Wall to turn on all warnings to see if there's anything else contributing

Comment: When I compile the code in your question with gcc on Cygwin, I get ```warning: type defaults to ‘int’ in declaration of ‘fun_ptr’ [-Wimplicit-int]```, not a syntax error. When I add `int` after `typedef`, it compiles without error. If you're getting a syntax error after adding `int`, the problem is in code you haven't shown us. This is why we need a [mre] (read that link).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
typedef (*fun_ptr)(int**, int, int, char**, int, int);
```

That's *almost* how you'd define a name `fun_ptr` for a pointer-to-function type. The only thing missing is the return type of the function. For example, if it returns `int`:

```
typedef int (*fun_ptr)(int**, int, int, char**, int, int);
```

(It looks like your code is incomplete, since you don't have any functions of that type, nor do you use `fun_ptr`. I presume you're just not finished.)

Comment: not really now it gives is this error

./source.c: line 11: syntax error near unexpected token `('
./source.c: line 11: `typedef int (*fun_ptr) (int**, int, int, char**, int, int);'

Comment: That I cannot reproduce. The only error I get when compiling your code and adding the missing return type is a linker error because there is no `main`. If you did not type this in yourself, make sure you didn't copy an invisible character or unicode character that looks like a `(` but isn't.

Comment: @AwaisAkbar  `typedef int (fun_ptr) (int*, int, int, char**, int, int);` is a syntactically valid declaration. If you're getting a syntax error, it's because of a problem on a previous line -- code that you didn't show us. This kind of thing is why we need a [mre].

Comment: @awaisakbar you are missing a `*` before `fun_ptr`: try with `(*fun_ptr)`.

Comment: @RobertoCaboni note how the text suddenly turns italics. That's the missing `*`.